# LaTeX - Project portfolio

Tags: overleaf, templates

I would like to create a portfolio with all my best work in it, and I would like it to look something similar to this the image in this webpage: https://loopcreativo.com/portfolio-crea-uno-saca-maximo-rendimiento-trabajo/

Does anyone have any idea where can I find a template suitable to my needs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This is far too broad and vague of a question.  What does your work consist of?  Images?  Text?  Something else?  This site revolves around specific questions: "I want to put these four images on one page, but when I use these commands, the last two images go to the next page.  Why?"

Answer (score 2):

Look for package `flowfram`, which was created for brochures and similar. See my recent examples:

- about [grid layout with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682526/245790)
- about [a layout-driven approach for designing a CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682657/245790)

Or use a layout-driven program like FrameMaker, Scribus (open source) or MS Publisher (may be on your computer already).